# Terracotta 4.3 initialization issue

Tags: exception, terracotta

I get the below exception when I try to start tomcat with my application. I have the ehcache-ee-2.10 and terracotta-toolkit jars in tomcat endorsed folder. I also do not have any transaction manager used in my application as there is no need for it. Is there a way to configure ehcache not to use any transaction. 
Any suggestions is very much appreciated.

```
DEBUG 2015-07-24 11:44:07,623 (net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler) - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
DEBUG 2015-07-24 11:44:07,623 (net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler) - Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
DEBUG 2015-07-24 11:44:07,631 (net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil) - propertiesString is null.
ERROR 2015-07-24 11:44:07,631 (net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration) - could not instantiate transaction manager lookup class: net.sf.ehcache.transaction.manager.DefaultTransactionManagerLookup
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration$RuntimeCfg.<init>(Configuration.java:1215)
at net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration.setupFor(Configuration.java:252)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:436)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:356)
at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
INFO  2015-07-24 11:44:07,633 (net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient) - Thread [Thread-2] [cacheManager: 'accountApplicationCache']: Creating new ClusteredInstanceFactory
ERROR 2015-07-24 11:44:07,636(org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountCacheManager' defined in URL [file:/C:/dev/apache-tomcat-7.0.16_1/webapps/account/WEB-INF/classes/context/account-cacheloader.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:426)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:356)
at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:65)
at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClusteredInstanceHelper.newClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClusteredInstanceHelper.java:157)
at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.createNewClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClient.java:180)
at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.createClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClient.java:129)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:463)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
... 24 more
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's your ehcache.xml looking like?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have incorrect tookit version. I have succeeded with dependecies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
            <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```